# Should I put my doclet and taglet in a seperate jar from the rest of my shared library classes?

Tags: java

I have multiple Web Applications that share a pair of common libraries(.jar files). I want to I've created some code for one of my apps to generate sitemaps and add an additional field with a page description to the result.  The page descriptions are generated with a Doclet at build time. This all works, for one of my sites. I'm looking at back porting this code into one of my shared libraries.  But I can't shake the feeling that maybe this should go into it's own separate library (Due to the doclet).

As a separate issue I've also created my own custom Taglet ExternalLink
so I can use `{@external.link http://www.google.com}` and get an HTML link
`<a href="http://google.com" >http://google.com</a>` in the resulting javadoc.

Currently I have the following shared libraries

- auth - Authentication/Authorization resources
- web  - Core Application/Look & Feel.

Should I put the doclet code in web? or should a new library:

- doc - sitemap/javadoc utilities

be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end Up creating a new .jar "doc" it contains the sitemap/Javadoc utilities as listend and then I've edited my poms to use it during build time to run the required processing on my web applications.